# (MUI) Can not extend default theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to extend MUI theme so that I could use both MUI's and custom theme:

```js
import { Box, styled } from '@mui/material'

const StyledBox = styled(Box)(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    height: '250px',
    width: '250px',
    backgroundColor: theme.custom?.success // this works
    // backgroundColor: theme.success.main // error???
  })
)
```

When rendering StyledBox, `backgroundColor: theme.success.main` does not work for some unknown reason. According to https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/, the `theme` object should have the `success` prop.

I tried to extend the imported MUI interfaces as follows, but it does not work either:

**src/types/theme.d.ts**

```js
import {
  // 1. import mui theme interfaces
  Theme as MUITheme,
  ThemeOptions as MUIThemeOptions
} from "@mui/material";

import React from "react";

export module "@mui/material/styles" {

  // 2. define custom theme interface
  interface ICustomTheme {
    custom?: { // 3. add custom prop
      success: React.CSSProperties["color"];
    };
  }
  
  // 4. let Theme and ThemeOptions interfaces extend both custom and mui intefaces
  interface Theme extends ICustomTheme, MUITheme {}
  interface ThemeOptions extends ICustomTheme, MUIThemeOptions {}

}
```

How can I extend the default theme so that I can use both `theme.custom.success` and MUI's default `theme.success.main`?